# Duplicated permalinks on a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

First I have www.mywebsite.com/blog/ Which is another wordpress Blog under www.mywebsite.com.

Then I created a page inside www.mywebsite.com which has a url of www.mywebsite.com/blog/.

I want to change the first www.mywebsite.com/blog into www.mywebsite.com/blog2 so It won't confuse me anymore.

After changing the permalinks in the admin panel. I can't access www.mywebsite.com/blog anymore.

Is there any way to access the page of the original www.mywebsite.com/blog2/wp-admin? and view the duplicated page www.mywebsite.com/blog/?

Please comments if my question confuses you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When moving your site, give the [guide to moving wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) or, in this case better, the [guide of changing the wordpress url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) a glance.

Suppose you changed the URIs where you cannot move the files, but still can access the login page (through a redirection or something) you can recover your installation easily.

`wp-login.php` can be used to (re-)set the URIs. Find this line:

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

and insert the following lines below:

```
 //FIXME: do comment/remove these hack lines. (once the database is updated)
update_option('siteurl', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
update_option('home', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
```

run it (once) and you are done. Test your site to make sure that it works right. If the change involves a new address for your blog, make sure you let people know the new address, and consider adding some redirection instructions in your .htaccess file to guide visitors to the new location. Delete those lines from your `wp-login.php`.